# jQuery Dynatree Plugin - how to disable a node?

Tags: jquery, dynatree

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html

Is it possible to disable individual nodes?
If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there's only the 'unselectable' node attribute.
A workaround could be to let the onQueryActivate callback return false.
And maybe add a custom class using the 'addClass' node option, to change the visual appearance.

http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/detail?id=68

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
        […]
        onActivate: function(node) {

          node.data.unselectable = true; //make it unselectable
          node.data.hideCheckbox = true; //hide the checkbox (more for UI purposes)

          node.render(true);


        },
        […]
    });
```

would disable the node on the fly

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the unselectable and hidecheckbox properties directly while creating the dynatree node.

This was exactly what I needed, I wanted to have certain parent items unselectable in the tree.

Thanks,

Rudy